# Why does callbackForNextFrame in SpriteKit takes a lot of CPU?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, instrumentation

I have a UIViewController which inside I am animating SKNodes. Those SKNodes all have a remove parent, so they will be always removed. However, I always see: "nodes: 1", so that is a bit strange. But this is the main problem:

[image]

I did not animate any SKNodes in that given time. Why is it taking up so much CPU? This is a debug session from a real device. I would like to get some advice on how to reduce this. When the SKNodes are not animating, this updates are unnecessary I think